# Save Files in SFTP in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to save the programatically generated CSV file in SFTP. Currently I'm saving the generated file in local PC path using following code.
How can I give the specific SFTP path to save the file?

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));              
        }          
        string fileName = "ReportName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmddyyyyhhmmss") + ".csv";   
        File.WriteAllText("E:\\LeafLogix\\ICS\\"+fileName+"", sb.ToString());            
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FtpWebRequest` object from `System.Net`.

Below documentation shows example of that:

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx) 
So instead of writing to file by `File.WriteAllText` you have to change your data stored in `sb` to bytes and upload them with `stream.Write([..])`.

To change `string` to bytes you can use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)`, and for UTF8: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString("user", 0);`